# overlays always in the back of the modal when loading

Tags: css

I want to process something and I use overlays for loading, everything work fine until I using for modal, when I process something and call overlays for loading it's always in the back of the modal, how can I call the overlays in front of the modal?

The following CSS I have used for overlays.

```
img#loading {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 45%;
    top: 30%;
    width: 150px;    
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /*dim the background*/
}
```

Comment: Increase the `z-index` value and keep `!important` if still not reflected.

Comment: better if seen in https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai thanks dude it's work

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

**HTML :**

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="overlay">
            <span class="close">×</span>
            <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.modal-content{
   position: relative;
}
```